# Form submit file attach

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a form with upload part . after uploading the file the user click on the send button. After that i want to send the file as a attachment to the receiver mail

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($_POST['myFile']) ){

    $attachname8=$_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $attachment8='';

    $output_dir="report/";
    //Filter the file types , if you want.

    if(!empty($attachname8))
    {
        if ($_FILES["myFile"]["name"] > 0)
        {
              echo "Error: " . $_FILES["myFile"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
             //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myFile"] ["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$_FILES["myFile"]["name"]);
             $attachment8="report/".$_FILES["myFile"]["name"];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is better then mine

Answer (score -1):

if you have `<input type='file' name='myFile' />` in your form, on submit, all you need is to get this named field in your php file as

```
if( isset($_POST['myFile']) ){
// means there is file submitted
// do process it here (store, edit, delete, whatever)
}
```